# How to run simulation for a set amount of clock cycles

Tags: vhdl, simulation, clock, cycle

To all,
I am new to VHDL. I have a working design however my simulation keeps running forever until I cancel the simulation. In the test bench how do I stop the simulation after x clock cycles? Is this done in the clock process?

```
clk_process :process
  begin
     clk <= '0';
     wait for clk_period/2;  
     clk <= '1';
     wait for clk_period/2;  
end process;
```

Please and Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VHDL-2008 :

```
if now >= clk_period * x then 
   std.env.stop;
end if;
```

In earlier revisions (still works in 2008 though!) :

```
assert now < clk_period * x report 
    "Stopping simulation : this is not a failure!" severity failure;
```

This latter curiosity (abusing an assert) is actually recommended in Janick Bergeron's book "Writing Testbenches"!

The clock process is as good a place as any for them but a separate process (probably sensitive to clock) for simulation control may be marginally cleaner design.

Comment: I want simulation to stop after 1000 clock cycles. could you please show me how you would integrate the VHDL-2008 code into the clock process? is this simply if clk >= clk_period * 1000 then std.env.stop; end if;

Comment: I already did.  Just set X to 1000. Note that your comment won't work because `clk` is not of type `time`.